# Doubts about infinite nested root

Tags: calculus, infinity

Find $f(a)=\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a^2-\sqrt{a^4-\cdots}}}$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}$.

My Attempt :

I consider $\frac{f(a)}{a}=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\cdots}}}$. Now to finding this limit is easy but I cannot prove the limit exists. Also I have another doubt can we write$\frac{f(a)}{a}$ as that infinite sum ? Since we consider infinitely many terms, I have doubts that this is true. Any help will be welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: RHS: let $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-...}} = t \implies t=\sqrt{1-t}$, square, simplify and solve.

Comment: is that a typo on $f(a)=\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a^2+\sqrt{a^4-\cdots}}}$ ??

Comment: See I know how to solve it. But I want to know how to prove that sum converges. And also if that division by $a$ is feasible or not. That is, after dividing if it actually is $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\cdots}}$ or not. And yes its a typo :(

Comment: most likely you can use induction to prove that it converges. but you need some element to be bound less than $1$

Comment: Try. I would love to see how induction helps, I got that when we consider upto nth term it oscillates between $a$ or $0$.

Answer (score 1):

consider a sequence $t_{n+1} = \sqrt{1 - t_n}$ with $0<t_1 < 1$, you can prove via induction that the limit converges because it's obvious.

also note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}t_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}t_{n} = t$ from which you get $t = \sqrt{1-t}$.

Comment: No obvious is not an answer. Proving rigorously is what I am having trouble with. And everyone my actual question involves $a$. No point trying this unless that division is possible which no one cared to clarify :( please help I am not much experienced in calculus.

Comment: @Joybangla are you familiar to proof by induction?

Comment: Oh yes I am familiar to it. But I don't think this sequence is monotone. Please tell me how to do it. And both answers say the limit exists for $t_0<1$ but $t_0=1$ thus it will oscillate and we are back to square one??

Comment: @Joybangla the sequence is not monotone for $t_0 = 1$ and most likely not for $t>0$ here in my answer I have assumed $0<t_0 <1$

Comment: Yes but for the infinite square root sum we are evaluating we have $t_1=1$ ??

Comment: @Joybangla then unfortunately, it does not converge like $1 + (-1)^n$

Comment: Thank you for clearing it..... Sorry for being so hopeless, I take time to understand..... Thanks a lot sir

Comment: @Joybangla haha ... you are welcome ;) I ain't sir :D

Answer (score 0):

For the expression
$$
\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\cdots}}}
$$
we can write this $t_0=1$, $t_{k+1}=\sqrt{1-t_k}$ where
$$
t_k=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\cdots\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1}}}}
\quad\text{containing $k+1$ terms ($k$ subtractions)}
$$
and check if the limit of $t_k$ exists. This is the definition of limit of infinitely nested expressions: take a finite number of nestings and let the number of nestings go to infinity and see if it converges.

However, we get $t_0=1$, $t_1=0$, $t_2=1$, $t_3=0$, etc. so it will keep alternating between $0$ and $1$ without converging.

If you start with $t_0\in(0,1)$, it will converge, and the limit $t$ will satisfy $t=\sqrt{1-t}$: i.e. $t=\frac{1}{2}(\sqrt5-1)$.

The only modification when you include the $a$ is that you get
$$
\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a^2-\cdots\sqrt{a^{2^{k-1}}-\sqrt{a^{2^k}}}}}=\sqrt{a}\cdot t_k
$$
as you've already figured out and take the limit of this instead with $a$ a constant.

Comment: But to evaluate $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-\cdots}}$ we have first term $1$, thus the limit does not exist?

Comment: @Joybangla: I've tried to clearify what is actually the definition of convergence for this kind of infinitely nested expression. Perhaps that was part of what caused some confusion. And, yes, the problem is that when you start with $t_0=1$ (actually $t_0=\sqrt{1}$) the sequence will alternate between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Then the limit does not exist? But normal methods yield a result? what should be done? Please help sir...Thanks for all the help you gave me

Comment: @Joybangla The limit does not exist. The "normal method" that you refer to is just the expession the limit would have had to satisfy if it had existed. It's like taking a sequence $t_0=a$, $t_{k+1}=2t_k$: **if** it has a limit, the limit will have to satisfy $t=2t$ which makes $t=0$, but this limit only exists if $a=0$.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up sir. Sorry I took a lot of time to understand.......